# can grow field object in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm working vb.net2010 and Crystal Reports for. NET Framework 4.0.

I have a text field in mysql db with RTF data, output the data to the report assigns by default a text field (IFieldObject).

The problem is that when the data exceed 4,922 words (with respect to microsoft Word) does not show the other data, I have activated the property can grow.

Could someone please tell me how I can show the rest of data are like a 2000 or 3000 words. Or Crystal Reports can not display more data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which crystal report version you are using???

Comment: using crystal reports 2011

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set a limit as to how many lines (not words) the report displays, make sure that when you set the "Can Grow" property to set the "Maximum Number of Lines" value to zero, which means there is no limit.

Cheers,

Chris

Since that doesn't seem to work, try right-clicking on the field, click on Format Field -> Paragraph tab -> Text Interpretation -> RTF text.

Comment: property "can grow" active and limit lines is 0, does not work, try to limit to 301 and shows 4 lines and increased to 401, shows nothing more.

Comment: Have you tried converting the RTF field to a string in the report?  cStr(fieldName)

Comment: the field does not show the option object cstr, only shows crStandardText, crRTFText and crHTMLText, selecting crStandardText displays a text blur

Comment: You will have to create a formula in your report to convert the field (if it will let you). Create a new formula, call it fieldConvert. In the formula you put cStr(fieldToConvert). Nothing else. Then put it in your report if CR will let you convert. If it does, right click the formula, format, click "Can Grow" and set lines to 0. Let me know how that goes.

Comment: mistake in expression CStr (FieldToConvert) says missing).

Comment: Could you provide me a screenshot of the formula and the error, please.

Comment: please, could you tell me how?

Comment: Excuse. I meant how to upload screenshot to the forum so that you can view.

Comment: Edit the original post and you will get an option to add a picture.

Comment: I can not send it because I need 10 points of reputation. give me a mailing address, if not much inconvenience. thanks

Comment: OK, I guess I need to explain further. The reason you got the error is because you used "(" at the beginning of the formual and "}" at the end. But, when I wrote cStr(FieldToConvert), I meant that you use the cStr to convert the field that contains the words. So "FieldToConvert" is just a placeholder. So the whole formula should look like cStr({contrato.FieldToConvert}) with "FieldToConvert" being the field that holds the words. I also uploaded the screenshot to the original post.

Comment: look, I'm new to the forum, even so I can not look at the screen capture you left in the original post. understanding what you sent, would read: CSRT (contrato.Texto) and accepts it but still the same (not shown all content), try this "cStr ({} contrato.Texto)" but says it does not recognize the {} . capture could help me by sending me mail. in advance thanks for the help, only I used Crystal 2 times and I have not used formulas.

Comment: The formula should look like this: cStr({contrato.FieldToConvert}). I also added another possible solution to my answer, please see the original answer.

Comment: I have already RTF text interpretation, "Can Grow" = Active, Limit = 0 and shows exactly 271 lines of text, 90 lines approximately are missing. Thanks for the help and patience I had.

Comment: uninstall and reinstall crystal reports, even so the field object shows all the text.

Comment: No, this equal, sorry for the translation.

Comment: I downloaded crystal reports version 13.0.7 for vs.net 2010, not that crystal does not show all content, whether text interpretation = none, shows all of the database, but if text = RTF conceals many lines of text.